# How-to clear custom style applied to element?

Tags: ckeditor

With Ckeditor 4x, when you add [custom styles](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles), you cannot use the "Remove format" [image] button it not remove the style (class).

[image]

It seem to be working good only when use the default styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to explain here because of design decisions taken in the past it is not as easy as it seems.

1. **By default only inline styles are removed with RemoveFormat**.
2. In order to remove block styles applied by the Styles drop-down, you need to unselect them in that drop-down (it works in toggle mode). You will than stay with a raw tag like H1 which you can change to another tag like P with the help of the Format drop-down. **It has to be done in that order.**
3. **It seems the best solution would be to overwrite the [addRemoveFormatFilter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addRemoveFormatFilter) method.** Let's say for example that you want to remove format only from h1-h3:

   ```
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id');
   editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( ev ) {
       editor.addRemoveFormatFilter( function( element ) {
            return  element.is( 'h3' ) || element.is( 'h1' ) || element.is( 'h2' );
       });             
   });
   ```

Of course you can use more advanced code here and not just a simple check if something is a particular element or not. You could for example use the [checkElementRemovable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-method-checkElementRemovable) method to check if a particular element matches a particular style.

Please note that it is necessary to select the whole block element to remove its format. In some cases e.g. a header holding a floated image it might be necessary to select this element using the element's path because it is hard to select it using the mouse.

Comment: focused on block styles, but if you're interested in removing inline styles then you can just use `addRemoveFormatFilter()` and `style.checkElementRemovable()` – it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks you! I have used the latest solution.